# UTF-8 in psycopg3

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psycopg3

I'm refactoring a python code base that is using psycopg2 to psycopg3.

The code has calls to `<cursor>.mogrify()` which is not present in psycopg3.

The code has something like this ensure that the strings are in UTF-8:

```py
arg_str = cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x)
args_list.append(arg_str)
args_str = b','.join(args_list).decode("utf-8")
cur.execute(insert_query + args_str)
```

In the new codebase, I added `client_encoding="UTF8"` to the `psycopg.connect()` call

Do I still need to do something like this ensure that strings will be in UTF8 when passing to `execute()`?

```py
cur.execute("INSERT INTO data(name) values (%s)", name.encode("utf-8").decode())
```

Comment: I don't think you want to pass bytes here, unless the target column is `BYTEA`.  Pass a `str` and let psycopg3 handle encoding.

Comment: So to rephrase that, "no, don't."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to handle encoding in both psycopg2 and psycopg3 is to

- set the encoding on the connection or via `SET client_encoding TO ...`
- pass `str` values to `cursor.execute` and let the connector handle encoding (and decoding)

So the correct code using psycopg3 is

```py
cur.execute("INSERT INTO data(name) values (%s)", (name,))
```

See the docs for [string adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/adapt.html#strings-adaptation).

The psycopg2 code in the question seems to be unnecessarily complicated, something like this would have worked just as well (assuming Python3):

```py
x = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(x))
insert_query = """INSERT INTO tbl (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) VALUES ({})""".format(placeholders)
cur.execute(insert_query, args)
```